# How to disable speed camera notifications in maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, maps

Google maps has recently introduced speed camera notifications, and I had the misfortune of experiencing these for the first time yesterday.

Personally I find the audio "speed camera ahead" very annoying and distracting, and would like to disable it. I don't mind the little beep or the icon on the map, but I'm also quite happy to lose them if it means getting rid of the spoken announcement.

However much I search, I can't find an option to remove this, or any information on the internet about disabling this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No they seem to have implemented it woth no option to turn it iff. Keep complaining on the feedback. I think it's distracting and dangerous (since it doesnt tell you the limit)